# Accessing the API response on Google Sheets

Tags: json, api, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am consuming the following API of Merriam Webstar, which is returning the following response,

```
meta:{  
    id:"umpire",
    uuid:"95702747-e10f-4738-895c-c04301c0799b",
    src:"int_thes",
    section:"alpha",
    target:{  
        tuuid:"897edcad-2e88-4ab7-b81b-170ddf8eb4ec",
        tsrc:"collegiate"
    },
    stems:[  
        "umpire",
        "umpires"
    ],
    syns:[  
        [  
            "arbiter",
            "arbitrator",
            "judge",
            "referee"
        ]
    ],
    ants:[  

    ],
    offensive:false
},
hwi:{  
    hw:"umpire"
},
fl:"noun",
def:[  
    {  
        sseq:[  
            [  
                [  
                    "sense",
                    {  
                        dt:[  
                            [  
                                "text",
                                "a person who impartially decides or resolves a dispute or controversy "
                            ],
                            [  
                                "vis",
                                [  
                                    {  
                                        t:"Mom usually acts as {it}umpire{/it} in our frequent squabbles over the sailboat."
                                    }
                                ]
                            ]
                        ],
                        syn_list:[  
                            [  
                                {  
                                    wd:"arbiter"
                                },
                                {  
                                    wd:"arbitrator"
                                },
                                {  
                                    wd:"judge"
                                },
                                {  
                                    wd:"referee"
                                }
                            ]
                        ],
                        rel_list:[  
                            [  
                                {  
                                    wd:"justice"
                                },
                                {  
                                    wd:"magistrate"
                                }
                            ],
                            [  
                                {  
                                    wd:"intermediary"
                                },
                                {  
                                    wd:"mediator"
                                },
                                {  
                                    wd:"negotiator"
                                }
                            ],
                            [  
                                {  
                                    wd:"conciliator"
                                },
                                {  
                                    wd:"go-between"
                                },
                                {  
                                    wd:"peacemaker"
                                },
                                {  
                                    wd:"reconciler"
                                }
                            ],
                            [  
                                {  
                                    wd:"decider"
                                }
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            ]
        ]
    }
],
shortdef:[  
    "a person who impartially decides or resolves a dispute or controversy"
]
```

Now, I am consuming this API in Google Sheets using the script [ImportJSON](https://blog.fastfedora.com/projects/import-json).

Problem is, I am  not able to access the def->sseq->dt->t - Mom usually acts as {it}umpire{/it} in our frequent squabbles over the sailboat.

This is the call i am making,

```
=ImportJSON(CONCATENATE("https://dictionaryapi.com/api/v3/references/ithesaurus/json/"&$A4&"?key=<KEY>"), "/def/sseq/dt/t", "noHeaders")
```

**EDIT**

> I have already accessed,
>
> 1. /shortdef
> 2. /meta/syns
> 3. /meta/ants
> 4. /fl
>
> And trying to access,
>
> 1. def->sseq->dt->t - Mom usually acts as {it}umpire{/it} in our frequent squabbles over the sailboat.

How can i access the said string?

Comment: Where can I see the value of `vi` of `/def/sseq/dt/vi/t` from your sample value in your question? And also, can you provide the output you expect?

Comment: I am trying to get `Mom usually acts as {it}umpire{/it} in our frequent squabbles over the sailboat.`. But I am not able to reach beyond `sseq`.
`/def/sseq` is giving, `sense, [object][object]` and `/def/sseq/dt` is giving, `#REFERROR`

Comment: Thank you for replying. You want to retrieve the value of `a person who impartially decides or resolves a dispute or controversy` from `def[0].sseq[0][0][1].dt[1][1][0].t`. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, in your situation, is it required to use ImportJson? Because I couldn't find the method for directly retrieving the value from such nested array using it. If you can use other script, I think that more simple script might be created. How about this?

Comment: I have updated my question. And I have a list of 500 important words and I want full details on them. The fastest and easiest way I could find to consume API was google sheet via `IMPORTJSON`. If there are any alternatives which can do that including concatenating the array with a delimiter (eg Synonyms) and produce multiple columns for more than one large groups (eg. one block for noun and another for verb each having full set of ants, syns, and example.)

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I couldn't understand whether my understanding for your goal is correct. I apologize for my poor English skill. And, unfortunately, I cannot still find `vi` of `/def/sseq/dt/vi/t` in your sample value. Where can I find it? And also, I cannot understand about `I have a list of 500 important words`. Can I ask you about the relationship between this and your question? I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: Im sorry, that was my bad. There is no `vi`, it was `vis`. And you wrote `def[0].sseq[0][0][1].dt[1][1][0].t` is pointing towards `a person who impartially decides or resolves a dispute or controversy` but actually `def[0].sseq[0][0][1].dt[1][1][0].t` is `Mom usually acts as {it}umpire{/it} in our frequent squabbles over the sailboat.`.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I thought that I could correctly understand about your goal. So I proposed 2 sample scripts for achieving your goal. Could you please confirm it? If those were not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the value of `Mom usually acts as {it}umpire{/it} in our frequent squabbles over the sailboat.` from `def[0].sseq[0][0][1].dt[1][1][0].t`.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find the method for directly retrieving the value you expect using ImportJson. So in this answer, I would like to propose 2 patterns of scripts for retrieving the value using Google Apps Script.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, a recursive function is used for retrieving the value. When you use this script, please put `=SAMPLE1(CONCATENATE("https://dictionaryapi.com/api/v3/references/ithesaurus/json/"&$A4&"?key=<KEY>"))` to a cell.

#### Sample script:

```
function SAMPLE1(url) {
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true});
  if (res.getResponseCode() != 200) return res.getContentText();

  const getValues = (data, contents = []) => {
    for (let key in data) {
      if (key === "t") contents.push(data[key]);
      if (typeof data[key] === "object") getValues(data[key], contents);
    }
    return contents;
  }

  return getValues(JSON.parse(res.getContentText()));
}
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, `JSON.parse` is used for retrieving the value. When you use this script, please put `=SAMPLE2(CONCATENATE("https://dictionaryapi.com/api/v3/references/ithesaurus/json/"&$A4&"?key=<KEY>"))` to a cell.

#### Sample script:

```
function SAMPLE2(url) {
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true});
  if (res.getResponseCode() != 200) return res.getContentText();
  
  var value = [];
  JSON.parse(res.getContentText(), (k, v) => {
    if (k == "t") value.push(v);
  });
  return value;
}
```

### Note:

- In these sample scripts, the response value from the URL is the JSON object in your question.
- In these sample script, when there are multiple values of `t` in the object, those are retrieved. Pleaes be careful this.

### References:

- [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)
- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: I understand you're trying to exclusively push all values of `t` in a stack. And that is the only optimal way I can see but it comes with only one drawback, lack of mapping with the parts of speech. I appreciate your efforts and detailed solution to this problem. It'll help other as well. Thank you.

Comment: @Mercurial Thank you for replying. From your goal, I thought that I could understand your goal, and I proposed above sample scripts. If I misunderstood your goal, I have to apologize. So about `lack of mapping with the parts of speech`, can I ask you the values you expect? I would like to think of it.

Comment: How about we start anew... We have some English words and we have to find `1. Part of Speech 2. Meaning(s) 3. Synonyms 4. Antonyms 5. Usage`. Now some words have more than one part of speech, like they can be noun as well as verb. So we need to add both entries for such words.

Comment: @Mercurial Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about the values you expect from your replying. So I also agree with `How about we start anew`. In order to correctly understand about your next goal, so can you post it as new question by including more information? By this, I would like to try to understand about it. How about this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64502611/handling-multiple-rows-returned-by-importjson-script-on-googlesheets I have updated the question here.

Comment: @Mercurial Thank you for your response. I would like to check it.